# Postman | Error: Parse Error: Invalid character in chunk size

Tags: postman

I am using Postman to send a request that takes xml in the body request and return xml in the response. I have set my accept as */* because I want to accept anything that server can give.

However, for whatever reason, randomly I am getting the following error in the Postman console:

> Error: Parse Error: Invalid character in chunk size

I cannot seem to be able to see the raw response in postman through tests section. How do I know if there is some invalid character somewhere?

Any suggestion, why it will work sometime and sometime it will not for the same request and response.

```
GET https://localhost:44368/turtle
Error: Parse Error: Invalid character in chunk size
Request Headers
SOAPAction: http://asdfas
x-commbank-entity: asdf
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
destination: https://asdfada
Authorization: Basic asdfadsfsaf=
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: bdb896c6-cd6a-469e-b7fe-7f33dfdca942
Host: localhost:44368
Connection: keep-alive
Request Body
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the way API was written, it was returning duplicate header key. The moment I distinct, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case,I am using lumen a microservice of laravel.I was using guzzle for passport response, i have changed the value of what the login function is returning inside my controller.I have changed to `return $guzzleResponse->withoutHeader('Transfer-Encoding');` instead of `return $guzzleResponse;` ,and it worked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I was tried Laith answer, It actually works. But, I can't use the response as value in another API request.

Instead of that, I recommend using  `return json_decode($response->getBody())`